# Change 'export default' to named export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

I have the following export:

```
import { compose } from '@ngrx/core/compose';

export default compose(storeLogger(), combineReducers)({
  events: fromEvents.eventsReducer,
  subscriptions: fromSubscriptions.subscriptionsReducer
});
```

I want to export as a named function, not default. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { compose } from '@ngrx/core/compose';

export const name = compose(storeLogger(), combineReducers)({
  events: fromEvents.eventsReducer,
  subscriptions: fromSubscriptions.subscriptionsReducer
});
```